# Changing data on SQL

Tags: sql

If I put new column or new value on rows, does it change the data on the database that I'm using to query the data? Let's say I have database 'A' and I'm working with table 'B'. Then, if I decide to put a new column on table 'B', will this also change the whole table 'B' from database 'A'? Or  will this only show on the result tab, without changing the real data?

Comment: Please tag your database which you are using now ? and do you want to add some value in the selection and give it a new column name or you want to modify the table structure by adding new column ?

Comment: i want to do both and I want to know whether it will affect the database or not.

Answer (score 0):

**DDL** makes changes to database. Like if you are doing

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```

Yes, it will update in database.

As you mentioned you just started learning so possibly you are fetching records in new column while selecting. Like

```
SELECT table_name.column + table_name.column2  AS new_column_name, table_name.column, table_name.column2
FROM table_name
```

In above case it will not make any change in database.

Comment: @katlew if it answers your question then this can be accepted. So it will help others too.